# find a and b parameters Chebyshev's inequality sampling

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, sampling

Given a random variable $X$ and $100$ samples $X_1, \dots, X_{100}$ chosen i.i.d., let $X^* = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{100} X_i / 100$. $\operatorname{Var}[X] =\sigma^2=9 $ and $E[X] = \mu $.
$\Pr[a\le X^*-\mu\le b] \geq 0.9$

**find $a$ and $b$ using Chebyshev's inequality**.

I don't know how to approach this question because every question I have saw using Chebyshev's inequality one parameter but here there is two.

**Update**

$ \Pr[a\le X^*-\mu\le b] = \Pr[|X^∗−μ|≤(b−a)/2]$

$  \Pr[|X^∗−μ|^2≤(\frac{b-a}{2})^2] = 1-\Pr[|X^∗−μ|^2>(\frac{b-a}{2})^2] \ge 1-\frac{E[X^* -\mu]^2}{(\frac{b-a}{2})^2} =     1- \frac{Var(X^*)}{(\frac{b-a}{2})^2}$

$ Var(X^*) = \frac{(\sigma)^2}{100} = 0.09 $

$ 1-\frac{0.09}{(\frac{b-a}{2})^2} = 0.9 $

Comment: The easiest way is to just *decide* the interval is symmetric around $\mu$ which reduces the number of parameters. These a and b are never unique anyway.

Comment: @Ian 
Do you mean , convert it to this $\Pr[|X^*-\mu| \le (b-a)/2] $

Comment: That's right. ${}$

Comment: @Ian Thanks , I have updated the question by adding an attempt to solve the question , can you check if my steps were legal ?

Comment: Looks generally right (assuming you want the optimal choice). Now just solve for $b-a$.